# openCV track object in video and obtain a better image from multiple frames

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm working on detecting license plates with openCV, python and a raspberry pi. Most of it is already covered. What I want is to detect the ROI (Region of interest) of the plate, track it on a few frames and add those together to get a more clear and crisp image of the plate.
I want to get a better image of the plate by taking the information from several frames. I detect the plate, and have a collection of plates from several frames, as many as I wish and as many as the car is moving by the camera. How can I take all those and get a better version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your frame rate is fast enough to get a decent still of the moving car. When filming, each frame will most likely be blurry, and our brain pieces together the number plate on playback. Of course a blurry frame is no good for letter recognition, so is something you'll need to deal with on the hardware side, rather than software side.

Remember the old saying: Garbage in; Garbage out.